# Configurable product not linking simple products when using Magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, magmi

I am using the following headers, which I believe are fine:

> sku|attribute_set|type|super_attribute_pricing|simple_skus|configurable_attributes|var_sku
>
> test11|Medlinev01|simple||||1
>
> testconf11|Medlinev01|configurable|test11,test22,test33|var_sku||

The issue, I believe, relies on the fact that Magento tries to add already linked products, so when I manually go into the configurable product menu, within the associated products tab, and hit the reset button they appear to work just fine.

However, when I try to associate them directly from the Magmi file, they dont work. The products are all created (both the simple and the configurable).

Answer (score 1):

you have to enable this setting at magmi when you upload configurable product please check below setting and let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think some missing from header so product is not visible after reset filter display, Magmi version 0.7 aur Magento 1.9.x. Including visibility in the header which are working fine.

sku|attribute_set|type|super_attribute_pricing|simple_skus|configurable_attributes|var_sku|visibility

simple product visibility is 1 and configurable product visibility is 4.

Answer (score -1):

try to reindex, even if it is not required after import with magmi.